# pyinstaller let pynput very slow

Tags: pynput

I developed a very large script in python on raspberry and I am using pynput module to read keyboard and barcode reader, and it run very good, very fast. I am using the program below:

def on_press(key):

```
kp = str(key)
kp = kp.replace("'", "")
try:
    s.send(kp.encode())
except BrokenPipeError:
    conect_socket()
```

def on_release(key):

```
pass
```

All code of my script is in this area, and work very good...

l = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)

l.start()

After that I convert it using pyinstaller, all modules work very well ( pad4pi, threading, socket), but when I read a data from keyboard or barcode reader the result is very slow to the server.
Somebody can help me?

Thank you in advanced

Prof. Wagner Ideali

Comment: I found the problem. I need to let a terminal open and the pynput works very good

Comment: Can you please explain your solution, I have the same problem. Under development everything is working fine, But after packaging the app with pyinstaller, pynput stops responding something and only after pressing the app everything is refreshing.

Comment: My solution was to run the lxterminal before to run my program.